# Synchronize page change of PageView and Slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview, flutter-slider

In my app, I have a `PageView` and a `Slider`. When I scroll the `PageView`, I expect the `Slider` to change its value, and when I slide the `Slider` I expect the page of the `PageView` to change as well. For this, I have a state to be the `value` of the `Slider`, and in `onChanged` I will have the change its value, and in `onChangeEnd` will animate the `PageView` to the desire position:

```
Slider(
   value: _sliderValue,
   onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
         _sliderValue = val;
      });
   },
   onChangeEnd: (val) {
      _controller.animateToPage(val.toInt(),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
      },
   max: (pages.length - 1).toDouble())
```

And in `PageView`, I have to update the `_sliderValue` as well, so it works when I scroll the `PageView`:

```
PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (page) {
    setState(() {
       _sliderValue = page.toDouble();
    });
  },
)
```

Problem is, I now have 2 places that I change the `_sliderValue` - one in `onChanged` for the `Slider` to be responsive, one in `onPageChanged` to work with scrolling. This makes the slider jarring when I press repeatedly on it.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the problem in this case lies in the fact that for every page change, the `onPageChanged` callback of the `PageView` is triggered. For example if we are at page 1 and use the `Slider` to move to page 5, then `onPageChanged` will be called 4 times (for page 2-3-4-5) and as a result the value state of the `Slider` will be changed repeatedly for 4 times. This causes the thump of the `Slider` to jump all over the places.

I attempted to fix it by having a `Timer` inside `onPageChanged` to wait for a certain amount of time before trigger the `setState`, so it only fires after the last page change is completed.

```
// Define a Timer object in your state
Timer _timer;
```

```
PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: (page) {
    // If there is a Timer running, cancel it
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    // Setup a new Timer
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      setState(() {
        _sliderValue = page.toDouble();
      });
    });
  },
)
```

This might seem hacky and the result is actually not perfect (when you scroll the page manually, the `Slider` will have to wait 300ms before updating its value) but it is an improvement nonetheless. If anyone has a better solution, I'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use val.round() instead of val.toInt().

```
            Slider(
            value: _sliderValue,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                _sliderValue = val.round().toDouble(); // this line changed.
              });
            },
            onChangeEnd: (val) {
              _controller.animateToPage(val.round(), // this line changed.
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
            },
            max: (pages.length - 1).toDouble()),
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. The real problem is having 2 state changes that overlap each other.

Comment: Are there two widgets are in Stack?

Comment: No they are not. The Slider is at the bottom and the PageView is above it.

Comment: I've been thinking, and I think you should create a new customized widget. If you really don't like the way you post it now.